# scales=free does not react in ggplot with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a lineplot with two facets. Here is the dataset:

```
to_plot <- structure(list(date = structure(c(12600, 12600, 12600, 12600, 
12631, 12631, 12631, 12631, 12662, 12662, 12662, 12662, 12692, 
12692, 12692, 12692, 12723, 12723, 12723, 12723, 12753, 12753, 
12753, 12753, 12784, 12784, 12784, 12784, 12815, 12815, 12815, 
12815, 12843, 12843, 12843, 12843, 12874, 12874, 12874, 12874, 
12904, 12904, 12904, 12904, 12935, 12935, 12935, 12935, 12965, 
12965, 12965, 12965, 12996, 12996, 12996, 12996, 13027, 13027, 
13027, 13027, 13057, 13057, 13057, 13057, 13088, 13088, 13088, 
13088, 13118, 13118, 13118, 13118, 16344, 16344, 16344, 16344, 
16375, 16375, 16375, 16375, 16405, 16405, 16405, 16405, 16436, 
16436, 16436, 16436, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16495, 16495, 
16495, 16495, 16526, 16526, 16526, 16526, 16556, 16556, 16556, 
16556, 16587, 16587, 16587, 16587, 16617, 16617, 16617, 16617, 
16648, 16648, 16648, 16648, 16679, 16679, 16679, 16679, 16709, 
16709, 16709, 16709, 16740, 16740, 16740, 16740, 16770, 16770, 
16770, 16770, 16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 16832, 16832, 16832, 
16832, 16861, 16861, 16861, 16861, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 
16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16983, 
16983, 16983, 16983, 17014, 17014, 17014, 17014, 17045, 17045, 
17045, 17045, 17075, 17075, 17075, 17075, 17106, 17106, 17106, 
17106, 17136, 17136, 17136, 17136, 17167, 17167, 17167, 17167, 
17198, 17198, 17198, 17198, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17257, 
17257, 17257, 17257, 17287, 17287, 17287, 17287, 17318, 17318, 
17318, 17318, 17348, 17348, 17348, 17348, 17379, 17379, 17379, 
17379, 17410, 17410, 17410, 17410, 17440, 17440, 17440, 17440
), class = "Date"), wave = c("Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", "Hartz_IV", "Pegida", 
"Hartz_IV"), type = c("Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity", "Issue salience", "Issue salience", "Party popularity", 
"Party popularity"), value = c(NA, 71.3381555153707, NA, 9.91085474567383, 
NA, 78.1039755351682, NA, 11.2076455256299, NA, 73.9750445632799, 
NA, 10.0549882168107, NA, 72.5748502994012, NA, 9.25831202046036, 
NA, 71.8585622443016, NA, 8.41949778434269, NA, 68.7237866986219, 
NA, 7.89902280130293, NA, 71.9364161849711, NA, 7.74731823599523, 
NA, 79.7647058823529, NA, 5.15384615384615, NA, 87.2630331753554, 
NA, 6.97674418604651, NA, 80.3149606299213, NA, 7.27708916433427, 
NA, 79.9878345498783, NA, 9.35085007727975, NA, 78.6594529606252, 
NA, 13.2875143184422, NA, 75.5769792579609, NA, 16.243847027641, 
NA, 79.1672711446395, NA, 13.2208418320044, NA, 77.2151898734177, 
NA, 10.7784431137725, NA, 70.7051032333463, NA, 9.9642431466031, 
NA, 71.5869311551925, NA, 12.0183136207554, NA, 74.00828892836, 
NA, 9.932785660941, 20.4423022398639, NA, 8.86486486486486, NA, 
29.1895010095183, NA, 5.49249359209081, NA, 31.1304347826087, 
NA, 4.83056957462149, NA, 42.4705882352941, NA, 5.56177678238149, 
NA, 32.7455919395466, NA, 6.75039246467818, NA, 28.3888228299643, 
NA, 5.50493545937737, NA, 44.1956393635828, NA, 4.93920972644377, 
NA, 36.2768496420048, NA, 3.50467289719626, NA, 30.7692307692308, 
NA, 4.04485382458951, NA, 48.7492373398414, NA, 3.04975922953451, 
NA, 72.1604938271605, NA, 3.69761709120789, NA, 81.8697729988053, 
NA, 5.14764565043895, NA, 85.4637336504162, NA, 6.75729708116753, 
NA, 80.3231390652048, NA, 9.53678474114441, NA, 78.9630512514899, 
NA, 9.58795562599049, NA, 79.6600403341976, NA, 12.6798910929599, 
NA, 80.632183908046, NA, 10.5672105672106, NA, 67.6506024096386, 
NA, 12.298682284041, NA, 68.7082728592163, NA, 10.3050595238095, 
NA, 61.9558735837806, NA, 12.5674633770239, NA, 61.1953352769679, 
NA, 10.8452335005789, NA, 50.6347800413345, NA, 9.35446463084654, 
NA, 58.288125376733, NA, 10.5347166799681, NA, 58.3232077764277, 
NA, 11.3076923076923, NA, 56.4117822076763, NA, 10.9069585613761, 
NA, 44.9571132800946, NA, 10.0578034682081, NA, 52.0665901262916, 
NA, 9.13818722139673, NA, 48.3361534122955, NA, 9.9236641221374, 
NA, 44.424882629108, NA, 7.58468335787923, NA, 43.4916718075262, 
NA, 6.68764752163651, NA, 41.0905002810568, NA, 6.81818181818182, 
NA, 31.9174041297935, NA, 6.67634252539913, NA, 34.3841214244016, 
NA, 6.72238372093023, NA, 35.1091703056769, NA, 6.96480938416422, 
NA, 37.210186240973, NA, 7.85042100049529, NA, 32.9296527159394, 
NA, 7.52759381898455, NA, 33.3132892363199, NA, 8.8734835355286, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -220L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

it's two time periods, for which I would like to have two facets, with a "free" x axis.

I have tried versions of the following code:

```
ggplot(to_plot, aes(x=date, y=value, linetype=type)) +
  geom_line() +
  # facet_wrap(~ wave, scales="free") +
    facet_grid(. ~ wave, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_linetype_manual(breaks = c("Party popularity", "Issue salience"),
    values = c("solid", "dashed")) + 
  ylab("Share (percentage point)") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%Y", date_breaks = "5 month", date_minor_breaks = "1 month",
               limits = c(min(to_plot$date), max = max(to_plot$date)), expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="bottom",
        legend.key.width = unit(2,"cm"), axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

Unfortunately I could not get the facets to work correctly. I am not sure what is going on here, I'd appreciate any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying limits on the facets' axes, which you need to remove. You should also filter out all the rows which have `NA` in the `value` column:

```r
ggplot(dplyr::filter(to_plot, !is.na(value)), 
       aes(x=date, y=value, linetype=type)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE) +
  facet_grid(. ~ wave, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_linetype_manual(breaks = c("Party popularity", "Issue salience"),
    values = c("solid", "dashed")) + 
  ylab("Share (percentage point)") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%Y", 
               date_breaks = "5 month", 
               date_minor_breaks = "1 month",
               expand = c(0, 0)) +
  guides(x = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title= element_blank(), 
        legend.position="bottom",
        legend.key.width = unit(2, "cm"), 
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]